# Customer detail Problem when FPC is enable

Tags: magento-2.1, full-page-cache, varnish

I have custom page where i have to display current login customer name,email,etc..

i logged in to one customer and go to my custom page it shows correct data than i log out and logged in with another customer and go to my custom page it shows wrong data(last logged in customer data) when FPC is enable

my block file code

```
$customerSession = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
if ($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
   $custId = $customerSession->getCustomerId();
   $billingId =  $customerSession->getCustomer()->getDefaultBilling();
   $address = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Address')->load($billingId);
   $customer = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Customer')->load($custId);
   $custInfo['groupId'] = $customer->getGroupId();
   $custInfo['name'] = $customer->getName();
   $custInfo['email'] = $customer->getEmail();
}
```

How to solve this problem when FPC is enable